# Precise decimal multiplication (js-assessment)

Tags: javascript

I am working on js-assessment [numbers.js](https://github.com/rmurphey/js-assessment/blob/master/tests/app/numbers.js) exercise. I thought I should multiply decimal numbers by ten to the power number of digits (e.g. 0.22 -> 0.22*10^2 = 22) to do precise decimal multiplication in js. This solution was good for that test.

I checked the solution proposed by the author of that test and I can't figure out how is that algorithm working. Here is the code:

```
function adjust(num) {
    var exponent, multiplier;

    if (num < 1) {
      exponent = Math.floor( Math.log(num) * -1 );
      multiplier = Math.pow(10, exponent);

      return { adjusted: num * multiplier, multiplier: multiplier };
    }

    return { adjusted: num, multiplier: 1 };
  }
```

What is the proof that

> Math.floor( Math.log(num) * -1 )

is enough exponent?

Comment: This attempt seems to be futile, because when you get passed `0.1` or `0.2` in the test *as a float*, then you already have lost the "decimal" precision.

Comment: Could you please link where you found that proposed solution?

Comment: Here is the test: https://github.com/rmurphey/js-assessment/blob/master/tests/app/numbers.js

And here is the answer: https://github.com/rmurphey/js-assessment-answers/blob/master/app/numbers.js

Comment: What I mean by precision is :
console.log(0.2*0.1); --> 0.020000000000000004
console.log((0.2*10*0.1*10)/100); --> 0.02
so the second one is better solution for me.

Comment: Um, yes, but how do you know that `0.2` and not `0.20000000000000004` was passed in? How do you know that you needed to multiply by 10 and divide by 100?